# Get the previous scheduled parition date in a dagster asset

Tags: dagster

Is there a way to get the previous scheduled partition key in an asset?

If i use the below in a scheduled asset it will return a partition key even if the should_execute in the schedule is False:

```
@asset(partitions_def=partition_def)
def my_asset(context):
    current_partition_window = context.partition_time_window
    prev_window = daily_partitions_def.get_prev_partition_window(current_partition_window.start)
    prev_partition_key = prev_window.start
    return prev_partition_key

my_job = define_asset_job("my_job", selection=[my_asset], partitions_def=partitions_def)
```

e.g. if my partition is:

```
partitions_def = DailyPartitionsDefinition(start_date='2023-07-03', timezone='America/New_York', fmt='%Y-%m-%d', end_offset=1)
```

and my scheduled job is:

```
def skip_july_4th(context) -> bool:
    dt = context.scheduled_execution_time
    if '2023-07-04' in str(dt):
        return False
    else:
        return True

@schedule(job=my_job, should_execute=skip_july_4th, cron_schedule="40 22 * * 1-5", execution_timezone='America/New_York')
def nyse_schedule(context):
    partition_key = daily_partitions_def.get_partition_key_for_timestamp(
        context.scheduled_execution_time.timestamp()
    )
    request = us_job.run_request_for_partition(partition_key=partition_key)
    yield request
```

The example above will return a previous partition key of '2023-07-04' on '2023-07-05' even thou it will return False for the given `should_execute` function in the schedule. How can I get the previous scheduled partition key in the asset.